# Replacing Tub Spout with Diverter, should I be worried about the scratched copper pipe?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, copper-pipe

The diverter on my tub spout was completely stuck/seized so I'm in the process of replacing it - mostly following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9enj3s6wOeg&ab_channel=HomeMender). The one in the video (and similar ones) had a screw holding it together but mine did not, so I *think* you're supposed to be able to just turn the tub spout and it should come off. However, mine was completely stuck together so as I turned it it left behind scratches on the copper tube - you can see it almost looks like a thread since I was turning it as I pulled it off.

I'm about to put a new tub spout on, but should I be worried about the scratched pipe? Is there anything I should do before I put on the new tub spout?

[image: Img1]
[image: Img2]
[image: Img3]

Comment: That is not scratched, it is gouged.  Replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you, or someone else, had a screw holding the spout in place and just gouged the pipe while pulling and twisting the spout. You should replace the pipe. It could easily snap, break with a little pressure. Plus, any new spout will not seal correctly and could leak. Not sure how it's mounted in there but looks like you could cut the pipe where the gouge stops and sweat in a coupling and additional pipe.